# Is the Mizar System feasible for checking basic proofs?

Tags: self-learning

Learning mathematics can be intimidating at times and it can be very useful to have positive feedback when writing proofs for homeworks. Is the Mizar System suitable for this sort of task? I'm not sure if it is meant for casual use like this or if it requires a substantial amount of time to input a proof. Of course, I could spend the time downloading it and reading more about it, but I figured I would ask here to see if anyone has a direct answer or general advice.

Comment: "Formalization is relatively labor-intensive, but not impossibly difficult. Once one is versed in the system, it takes about one week of full-time work to have a textbook page formally verified." So, depends on whether that seems reasonable for casual use or not.

Additionally, the getting "versed in the system" is highly nontrivial in its own right.

Comment: @David Interesting, that's probably a bit long for what I had in mind, but I'll probably give it a try when I have more time